# VersionConflict in fastprogress

Tags: python, version-control, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

Please, I'm using Google Colab and Python3

I have a problem with VersionConflict in fastprogress. I have this code:

```
!curl -s https://course.fast.ai/setup/colab | bash
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from fastai.vision import *
from fastai.metrics import error_rate
import fastai
print(f'fastai: {fastai.__version__}')
print(f'cuda: {torch.cuda.is_available()}')


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
VersionConflict                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-01736c3668f8> in <module>()
      1 import warnings
      2 warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
----> 3 from fastai.vision import *
      4 from fastai.metrics import error_rate
      5 import fastai

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
    789                 # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
    790                 dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 791                 raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    792 
    793             # push the new requirements onto the stack

VersionConflict: (fastprogress 0.1.22 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('fastprogress>=0.2.1'))
```

I have also tried updating with (!pip install --upgrade fastprogress) but the message is already updated

```
Requirement already up-to-date: fastprogress in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.2.1)
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing the same problem just now. In my case, weirdly though, I can import successfully after **restarting the kernel**.

Comment: Thanks @Martian
I accessed the Runtime menu - Restart runtime
And then I didn't run the (!curl -s https://course.fast.ai/setup/colab | bash) command again. From then on my script worked

Comment: Yes, no other explanation until now.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was run the cel: from fastai.vision import * at first and then run the other cells such as :

> from google.colab import drive drive.mount('/content/gdrive',
>   force_remount=True) root_dir = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/" base_dir =
>   root_dir + 'fastai-v3/'

Answer (score 1):

I checked the versions of both fastai and fastprogress.
As of today (12/31/2019) Colab has

- fastai: 1.0.59
- fastprogress: 0.1.22

The command `!curl -s https://course.fast.ai/setup/colab | bash`
will update them to

- fastai: 1.0.60
- fastprogress: 0.2.1

when you do `from fastai.vision import *`, somehow the fastai.vision is still pointed to the old version while the fastprogress to the new one.

What I found from both solutions by @Martian and @John is that.

1. solution by @Martian, i.e. just **Restart runtime ...** when you encounter the issue and rerun the import line will import the new version.
2. the one by @John, i.e. running the import line first, will lead to the old version.